# Scrollview goes black when resuming activity

Tags: android, android-scrollview

When I navigate away from an activity with a ScrollView then return to it, the ScrollView goes black. On launch, the colours are correct. It's just when I navigate away and come back it goes black. I have tried setting the backgrounds of the ScrollView and the internal LinearLayouts but it makes no difference. The ScrollView is inflated by a fragment in a ViewPager, in case that makes a difference.

Any ideas why this may be the case?

Here is the XML

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_formatted"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <LinearLayout style="@style/LinearLayoutVertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_formatted"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_review_cd"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/LinearLayoutVertical.WrappedVertical"
            android:id="@+id/subject_rating_formatted">

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subject_formatted"
            style="@style/TextView.Subject.Bold"
            android:background="?darkBackground"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?darkBackground">

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating_formatted"
                style="@style/RatingBarFiveStar.Indicator.PointOneStep"
                android:background="?darkBackground"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stamp_formatted"
                style="@style/FormattedText.Stamp"
                android:background="?darkBackground"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headline_formatted"
            style="@style/TextView.Headline"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tags_formatted"
            style="@style/FormattedTitleValue"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/comment_formatted"
            layout="@layout/formatted_title_value"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/locations_formatted"
            layout="@layout/formatted_title_value"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/criteria_formatted"
            layout="@layout/formatted_title_value"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/facts_formatted"
            layout="@layout/formatted_title_value"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/images_formatted"
            layout="@layout/formatted_title_data"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Edit: here is the activity and fragment:

**Activity**

```
public class ActivityFormatReview extends FragmentActivity implements LaunchableUi,
        OptionSelectListener, FormattedPagerAdapter.FragmentsObserver {
    private static final String TAG = TagKeyGenerator.getTag(ActivityFormatReview.class);
    private static final String RETAIN_VIEW
            = TagKeyGenerator.getKey(ActivityFormatReview.class, "RetainView");
    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.view_pager;
    private static final int PAGER = R.id.pager;

    private FormattedPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private FragmentInitialiser mInitialiser;

    public ReviewNode getNode(ReviewId id) {
        return mAdapter.getNode(id);
    }

    public void remove(FragmentFormatReview fragment) {
        mAdapter.removeFragment(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(LAYOUT);

        Bundle args = getIntent().getBundleExtra(getLaunchTag());
        if (args == null) throwNoReview();

        AppInstanceAndroid app = AppInstanceAndroid.getInstance(this);
        ReviewNode node = app.unpackNode(args);
        if (node == null) throwNoReview();

        boolean isPublished = NodeLauncher.isPublished(args);

        mPager = findViewById(PAGER);
        mAdapter = new FormattedPagerAdapter(node, new NodeComparatorMostRecent(),
                getSupportFragmentManager(), this, isPublished);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mInitialiser = new FragmentInitialiser(app.getUi());
        mPager.addOnLayoutChangeListener(mInitialiser);
        mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(mInitialiser);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNoFragmentsLeft() {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTitle(String title) {
        mInitialiser.setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mAdapter.detach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(RETAIN_VIEW, true);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public String getLaunchTag() {
        return TAG;
    }

    @Override
    public void launch(UiTypeLauncher launcher) {
        launcher.launch(getClass(), getLaunchTag());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionSelected(int requestCode, String option) {
        FragmentFormatReview fragment = getVisibleFragment();
        return fragment != null && fragment.onOptionSelected(requestCode, option);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsCancelled(int requestCode) {
        FragmentFormatReview fragment = getVisibleFragment();
        return fragment != null && fragment.onOptionsCancelled(requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AppInstanceAndroid.setActivity(this);
    }

    @Nullable
    private FragmentFormatReview getVisibleFragment() {
        return mAdapter.getFragment(mPager.getCurrentItem());
    }

    private void throwNoReview() {
        throw new RuntimeException("No review found");
    }

    private class FragmentInitialiser implements ViewPager.OnLayoutChangeListener, ViewPager
            .OnPageChangeListener {
        private UiSuite mUi;

        private FragmentInitialiser(UiSuite ui) {
            mUi = ui;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int
                i6, int i7) {
            setTitle();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            setTitle();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }

        private void setTitle() {
            FragmentFormatReview fragment = getVisibleFragment();
            if (fragment != null) {
                setTitle(fragment.isPublished() ?
                        mAdapter.getTitle(fragment) : Strings.Screens.PREVIEW);
            }
        }

        private void setTitle(String title) {
            mUi.getCurrentScreen().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class FragmentFormatReview extends PagerAdapterBasic.PageableFragment implements
        ReviewNode.NodeObserver,
        DataReference.InvalidationListener,
        OptionSelectListener {
    private static final String ID = TagKeyGenerator.getKey(FragmentFormatReview.class,
            "ReviewId");
    private static final String PUBLISHED = TagKeyGenerator.getKey(FragmentFormatReview.class,
            "published");

    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_review_formatted;
    private static final int IMAGE = R.id.image_formatted;
    private static final int SUBJECT = R.id.subject_formatted;
    private static final int RATING = R.id.rating_formatted;
    private static final int HEADLINE = R.id.headline_formatted;
    private static final int STAMP = R.id.stamp_formatted;
    private static final int COMMENT = R.id.comment_formatted;
    private static final int TAGS = R.id.tags_formatted;
    private static final int CRITERIA = R.id.criteria_formatted;
    private static final int FACTS = R.id.facts_formatted;
    private static final int LOCATIONS = R.id.locations_formatted;
    private static final int IMAGES = R.id.images_formatted;
    private static final int DATA = R.id.section_data;
    private static final int IMAGE_PADDING = R.dimen.formatted_image_padding;
    private static final int IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER = R.drawable.image_placeholder;

    private static final ReviewViewParams.CellDimension FULL
            = ReviewViewParams.CellDimension.FULL;
    private static final ReviewViewParams.CellDimension HALF
            = ReviewViewParams.CellDimension.HALF;

    private boolean mIsPublished = true;
    private ReviewNode mNode;
    private UiSuite mUi;
    private RepositorySuite mRepo;
    private MenuUi mMenu;

    private CoverNodeBannerUi mCover;
    private ViewUi<TextView, String> mSubject;
    private ViewUi<RatingBar, Float> mRating;
    private ViewUi<TextView, RefDataList<DataTag>> mTags;
    private ViewUi<TextView, AuthorReference> mStamp;
    private FormattedSectionUi<RefCommentList> mComment;
    private FormattedSectionUi<RefDataList<DataCriterion>> mCriteria;
    private FormattedSectionUi<RefDataList<DataFact>> mFacts;
    private FormattedSectionUi<RefDataList<DataLocation>> mLocations;
    private FormattedSectionUi<ReviewItemReference<DataSize>> mImages;

    public static FragmentFormatReview newInstance(String nodeId, boolean isPublished) {
        //Can't use FactoryFragment as Support fragment rather than normal fragment
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ID, nodeId);
        args.putBoolean(PUBLISHED, isPublished);
        FragmentFormatReview fragment = new FragmentFormatReview();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    public boolean isPublished() {
        return mIsPublished;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageId() {
        return mNode.getReviewId().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        AppInstanceAndroid app = AppInstanceAndroid.getInstance(getContext());
        mUi = app.getUi();
        mRepo = app.getRepository();

        View v = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args == null) {
            noReview();
            return v;
        }

        mIsPublished = args.getBoolean(PUBLISHED);

        setNode(args);
        setMenu();

        setCover(v);
        setSubject(v);
        setRating(v);
        setStamp(v);
        setComment(v);
        setTags(v);
        setCriteria(v);
        setFacts(v);
        setLocations(v);
        setImages(v);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, android.view.MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        mMenu.inflate(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        return mMenu.onItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(ReviewNode child) {
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(ReviewNode child) {
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNodeChanged() {
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTreeChanged() {
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionSelected(int requestCode, String option) {
        return mMenu.onOptionSelected(requestCode, option);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsCancelled(int requestCode) {
        return mMenu.onOptionsCancelled(requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mNode.unregisterObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReferenceInvalidated(DataReference<?> reference) {
        if (getContainer() != null) getContainer().remove(this);
    }

    private FactoryCommands getCommandsFactory() {
        return mUi.getCommandsFactory();
    }

    private ConverterGv getConverter() {
        return mUi.getGvConverter();
    }

    private ActivityFormatReview getContainer() {
        try {
            return (ActivityFormatReview) getActivity();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void noReview() {
        AppInstanceAndroid app = AppInstanceAndroid.getInstance(getContext());
        CurrentScreen currentScreen = app.getUi().getCurrentScreen();
        currentScreen.showToast(Strings.Toasts.REVIEW_NOT_FOUND);
        currentScreen.close();
    }

    private void setNode(Bundle args) {
        String reviewId = args.getString(ID);
        if (reviewId == null) {
            noReview();
            return;
        }

        mNode = getContainer().getNode(new DatumReviewId(reviewId));
        mNode.registerObserver(this);
        ReviewReference reference = mNode.getReference();
        if (mNode.isLeaf() && reference != null) reference.registerListener(this);
    }

    private void setMenu() {
        AppInstanceAndroid app = AppInstanceAndroid.getInstance(getContext());
        UiSuite ui = app.getUi();
        MenuActionItem<GvData> upAction = new MaiUpAppLevel<>(app);

        MenuAction<?> action;
        if (mIsPublished) {
            OptionsCommand command
                    = getCommandsFactory().newReviewOptionsSelector(ReviewOptionsSelector
                    .SelectorType.ALL, new NodeAuthorId(mNode));
            MaiOptionsCommand<GvData> mai = new MaiOptionsCommand<>(command);
            action = new MenuOptionsAppLevel(Strings.Menu.REVIEWS, upAction, mai, ui);
        } else {
            action = new MenuUpAppLevel(Strings.Screens.PREVIEW, upAction, ui);
        }

        mMenu = new MenuUi(action);
    }

    private void update() {
        mCover.update();
        mImages.update();
        mSubject.update();
        mRating.update();
        mStamp.update();
        mTags.update();
        mComment.update();
        mLocations.update();
        mCriteria.update();
        mFacts.update();
    }

    @Nullable
    private Command launchView(GvDataType<?> type) {
        return mIsPublished ? newLaunchViewCommand(type) : null;
    }

    private void setCover(View v) {
        CellDimensionsCalculator calculator = new CellDimensionsCalculator(getActivity());
        CellDimensionsCalculator.Dimensions dims = calculator.calcDimensions(FULL, FULL, 0);
        Bitmap placeholder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER);

        mCover = new CoverNodeBannerUi((ImageView) v.findViewById(IMAGE), mNode,
                mRepo.getAuthorsRepo().getProfile(mNode.getAuthorId()).getProfileImage(),
                placeholder, dims);
        setLaunchOnClick(mCover, getCommandsFactory().newLaunchBespokeViewCommand(mNode,
                "Images", GvImage.TYPE));
    }

    private void setSubject(View v) {
        mSubject = new SubjectNodeUi((TextView) v.findViewById(SUBJECT), mNode, null);
    }

    private void setRating(View v) {
        mRating = new RatingBarTouchable((RatingBar) v.findViewById(RATING), mNode, null);
    }

    private void setStamp(View v) {
        mStamp = new StampNodeUi((TextView) v.findViewById(STAMP), mNode, mRepo.getAuthorsRepo());
        setLaunchOnClick(mStamp, launchAuthor());
    }

    private void setTags(View v) {
        mTags = new TagsNodeUi((TextView) v.findViewById(TAGS), mNode);
        setLaunchOnClick(mTags, GvTag.TYPE);
    }

    private void setComment(View v) {
        mComment = new CommentNodeUi(getSection(v, COMMENT), (TextView) v.findViewById(HEADLINE),
                mNode, launchView(GvComment.TYPE));
    }

    private void setLocations(View v) {
        mLocations = newDataUi(v, LOCATIONS, Strings.Formatted.LOCATIONS, GvLocation.TYPE,
                getConverter().newConverterLocations(), VhLocationFormatted.class,
                new SimpleViewUi.ReferenceValueGetter<RefDataList<DataLocation>>() {
                    @Override
                    public RefDataList<DataLocation> getValue() {
                        return mNode.getLocations();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void setCriteria(View v) {
        mCriteria = newDataUi(v, CRITERIA, Strings.Formatted.CRITERIA, GvCriterion.TYPE,
                getConverter().newConverterCriteria(), VhCriterionFormatted.class,
                new SimpleViewUi.ReferenceValueGetter<RefDataList<DataCriterion>>() {
                    @Override
                    public RefDataList<DataCriterion> getValue() {
                        return mNode.getCriteria();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void setFacts(View v) {
        mFacts = newDataUi(v, FACTS, Strings.Formatted.FACTS, GvFact.TYPE,
                getConverter().newConverterFacts(), VhFactFormatted.class,
                new SimpleViewUi.ReferenceValueGetter<RefDataList<DataFact>>() {
                    @Override
                    public RefDataList<DataFact> getValue() {
                        return mNode.getFacts();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void setImages(View v) {
        LinearLayout section = getSection(v, IMAGES);
        RecyclerView grid = section.findViewById(DATA);
        float padding = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(IMAGE_PADDING);
        CellDimensionsCalculator calculator = new CellDimensionsCalculator(getActivity());
        CellDimensionsCalculator.Dimensions dims = calculator.calcDimensions(HALF, HALF, (int)
                padding);

        ViewUi<RecyclerView, RefDataList<DataImage>> dataView = newGridUi
                (grid, VhImage.class, 1, (int) padding, dims, getConverter().newConverterImages(),
                        new SimpleViewUi.ReferenceValueGetter<RefDataList<DataImage>>() {
                            @Override
                            public RefDataList<DataImage> getValue() {
                                return mNode.getImages();
                            }
                        });

        mImages = new ImagesNodeUi(section, dataView, mNode);
    }

    private void setLaunchOnClick(ViewUi<?, ?> layout, GvDataType<?> type) {
        Command onClick = launchView(type);
        setLaunchOnClick(layout, onClick);
    }

    private void setLaunchOnClick(ViewUi<?, ?> layout, @Nullable Command onClick) {
        if (mIsPublished && onClick != null) layout.setOnClickCommand(onClick);
    }

    private <T1 extends HasReviewId, T2 extends GvData, Vh extends ViewHolder>
    ViewUi<RecyclerView, RefDataList<T1>>
    newGridUi(RecyclerView view, Class<Vh> vhClass,
              int span, int padding, CellDimensionsCalculator.Dimensions dims,
              DataConverter<T1, T2, ? extends GvDataList<T2>> converter,
              SimpleViewUi.ReferenceValueGetter<RefDataList<T1>> getter) {
        IdableDataList<T1> empty = new IdableDataList<>(getter.getValue().getReviewId());
        GvDataType<T2> dataType = converter.convert(empty).getGvDataType();

        GvDataRefAdapter<T1, T2, Vh> adapter
                = new GvDataRefAdapter<>(getter, converter, new VhFactory<>(vhClass), dims);

        Command onClick = mIsPublished ? newLaunchViewCommand(dataType) : null;
        view.addItemDecoration(new PaddedItemDecoration(padding));
        return new HorizontalGridUi<>(getContext(), view, adapter, span, onClick);
    }

    private Command newLaunchViewCommand(GvDataType<?> dataType) {
        return getCommandsFactory().newLaunchViewCommand(mUi.newDataView(mNode, dataType));
    }

    private Command launchAuthor() {
        return mUi.getCommandsFactory().newLaunchAuthorCommand(mNode.getAuthorId());
    }

    private <T extends HasReviewId, G extends GvData> DataExpandableUi<T>
    newDataUi(View v, int sectionId, String title, GvDataType<G> dataType,
              DataConverter<T, G, ?> converter, Class<? extends ViewHolder> vhClass,
              SimpleViewUi.ReferenceValueGetter<RefDataList<T>> getter) {
        DataExpandableUi<T> ui = new DataExpandableUi<>(getContext(), getSection
                (v, sectionId), title, getter, newVhFactory(vhClass), converter);
        setLaunchOnClick(ui, dataType);
        return ui;
    }

    @NonNull
    private ViewHolderFactory<ViewHolder> newVhFactory(final Class<? extends ViewHolder> vhClass) {
        return new ViewHolderFactory<ViewHolder>() {
            @Override
            public ViewHolder newViewHolder() {
                try {
                    return vhClass.newInstance();
                } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private LinearLayout getSection(View v, int id) {
        return (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(id);
    }

    private static class NodeAuthorId extends DatumAuthorId {
        private ReviewNode mNode;

        private NodeAuthorId(ReviewNode node) {
            super(node.getReviewId(), node.getAuthorId().toString());
            mNode = node;
        }

        @Override
        public ReviewId getReviewId() {
            return mNode.getReviewId();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return mNode.getAuthorId().toString();
        }
    }

    private static class PaddedItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
        private final int mPadding;

        PaddedItemDecoration(int padding) {
            mPadding = padding;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
                                   RecyclerView.State state) {
            outRect.right = mPadding;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 2: here is the manifest entry:

```
<activity            
 android:name=".ApplicationPlugins.PlugIns.UiPlugin.UiAndroid.Implementation.Act
ivities.ActivityFormatReview"
 android:configChanges="orientation"
 android:exported="true"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

Comment: You probably have something in your activities code that is influencing your app. Edit you post and add the activities code.

Comment: @Barns Thanks for the reply - have edited to include Activity and associated Fragment. Cheers.

Comment: Add the manifest entry of activity . And let me know did you get this behavior on each device or on some specific device ?

Comment: Is your scrollview visible and only colors are not showing or your scrollview is not at all visible?

If your scrollview is not showing try to make changes in your layout from scrollview to text view for temporary and check whether is it showing or not, as it might be fragment issue not the scrollview rendering issue.

Comment: @ADM: I am testing specifically on a LG V30+. I will try it on another device to see if it is device specific. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickR: Scrollview is visible and works normally. It is only the background colour that seems to switch to black when returning to the activity. Interestingly, if I navigate again away from the activity, it switches back to the correct colour just before it navigates away. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with setting image as background instead of color and check if it is working or not?

Comment: what is your app theme in application tag in the manifest?

Comment: One "hack" I can suggest is to nest the ScrollView in a FrameLayout, setting your ScrollView's background to transparent and FrameLayout background to your desired color. Does this impact the output?

Comment: What is in your style.xml? (style="@style/LinearLayoutVertical")

Comment: [scrollview causes black background to appear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11344512/3879456) This may help you!

Comment: @style/LinearLayoutVertical, what is inside this style?

Comment: @Karan Unfortunately that is something I have tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @PatrickR Inspired by your suggestion I set the background to a drawable with a solid color and that seemed to fix it - thanks! I'll write a solution and reference your comment cheers.

Comment: @MDP its actually just android:layout_width, android:layout_height set to match_parent and orientation set to vertical. Cheers.

Comment: @chdryra Well I think that's exactly your problem, `ScrollView children must set their layout_width or layout_height attributes to wrap_content` in your case the height should be set to wrap_content

Comment: @MDP Interesting, I wasn't aware of that. I tried changing the LinearLayout to be wrapped but it made no difference. However that's not to say some child view within the other layouts doesn't have a match_parent. However,  I don't want to have to go through all the different children and change them to wrapped content. Can you explain - or point me to a resource that explains - why match_parent would cause this issue please?

Comment: I don't know what are you looking for, but take a look at [here](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/) it might help.

Comment: @MDP thanks appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Patrick R.'s comment, I tried setting the background to a drawable with a solid color. I had tried setting a color directly previously before posting my question but it hadn't worked. Nor had wrapping the scrollview in a framelayout. However setting the background to a drawable with a solid color does seem to fix the problem

Scrollview:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_formatted"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
```

background.xml

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="?dominantBackground" />
</shape>
```

I have absolutely no idea why this works so cannot say for sure if it fixes the problem in all situations, but it does fix it for the situations in which I was able to repeatably generate the problem.

Comment: This is inspired by @PatrickR's comment so the bounty should go to him...

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. It means a lot. You can still up-vote my comment to have a reward for me!! :)

Comment: It's because of your styles and theme. take a look at these attributes in your theme in styles: `android:windowIsTranslucent` `android:background` `android:windowBackground` there is no rule for window background to always be white, if parent of your theme is holo light or material light etc yes it probably will be white, but if you don't inherit these themes, then android doesn't know what color the background should be and sets it to default which in your case is black.

Answer (score 0):

On your scrollview set a background

**in XML:**
`android:background="@color/Your_White_Color"`

Became like this

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_formatted"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="@color/Your_White_Color">
```

or in the **code**:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_formatted);
scrollView.setBackground(R.color.Your_White_Color);
```

Should be nice a print screen from the view to understand better

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this was the first thing I tried and it didn't work. However, I have tried wrapping the color in a drawable which seems to have fixed it for some reason....